# How to cover a grid with another grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

In Tikz I would like to display multiple overlapping grids such that the last one covers the previous ones. This is the code and the wrong output I get, where you can see the intermediate line of all grids. The `fill=white` parameter seems to not work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0, 0.5, ..., 1.5}
        \draw[fill=white, xshift=\i cm, yshift=-\i cm] (0, 0) grid (4, 4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Which part is wrong in the output?

Comment: Grid is is not a shape, it is composed from lines, so in it is nothing to fill.

Comment: [Is this what you want to achieve?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOtFw.png)

Comment: @Alenanno yes exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you like to get the following:

[image]

Above image is composed from square shapes. One way to do this is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \k in {0, 0.5, 1, 1.5}
{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\k cm,-\k cm)}]
    \foreach \i in {0, 1,...,4}
    {
        \foreach \j in {0,1,...,4}
            \node[draw, fill=white, minimum size=1 cm, outer sep=0pt]
                  at (\i, \j) {};
    }
    \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Simpler is to draw grid in rectangles with white fill:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0, 0.5, ..., 1.5}
{
\draw[fill=white, xshift=\i cm, yshift=-\i cm] (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
\draw[xshift=\i cm, yshift=-\i cm] (0, 0) grid (4, 4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before

Comment: So it cannot be done with grids, but with rectangles only?

Comment: @aretor, not only with grid. See addendum to answer.

Comment: The second solution is what I was searching for, thanks.